# read last 5 entries from xml in reverse order using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, reverse

I want to know how to modify the XSL to display the last 5 nodes in the reverse order from the XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='ResultXSL.xsl'?>
<Automation>
 <Run>
  <client1>
    <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>23</TotalTests>
    <Success>13</Success>
    <Failures>10</Failures>
  </client1>
  <client2>
    <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>4</TotalTests>
    <Success>0</Success>
    <Failures>4</Failures>
  </client2>
  <client3>
    <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>9</TotalTests>
    <Success>3</Success>
    <Failures>6</Failures>
    </client3>
</Run> 
<Run>
  <client1>
    <Date>26/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>23</TotalTests>
    <Success>13</Success>
    <Failures>10</Failures>
  </client1>
  <client2>
    <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>4</TotalTests>
    <Success>0</Success>
    <Failures>4</Failures>
  </client2>
  <client3>
    <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>9</TotalTests>
    <Success>3</Success>
    <Failures>6</Failures>
  </client3>
 </Run>
 <Run>
  <client1>
    <Date>27/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>23</TotalTests>
    <Success>13</Success>
    <Failures>10</Failures>
  </client1>
  <client2>
    <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>4</TotalTests>
    <Success>0</Success>
    <Failures>4</Failures>
  </client2>
  <client3>
    <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
    <TotalTests>9</TotalTests>
    <Success>3</Success>
    <Failures>6</Failures>
  </client3>
 </Run>
</Automation>
```

In the XSL below I am getting the last 5 nodes from the XML in correct order. How do we modify this to get the xml nodes in the reverse order?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"       xmlns:TESA="tesa.philips.com">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
</head>
<body>
<hr/>
<p>
  <table border="5"  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="1200">
    <tr>
      <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px;height:80">Date</th>
      <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Total Tests</th>
      <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Passed</th>
      <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Failure</th>
    </tr>
<xsl:variable name="vvr_count" select="count(Automation/Run)"/>
<xsl:variable name="vvr_latest10" select="number($vvr_count) - 5"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="Automation/Run">
<xsl:if test="$vvr_latest10 &lt;= position()">
      <tr>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client1/Date"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client1/TotalTests"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client1/Success"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client1/Failures"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client2/Date"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client2/TotalTests"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client2/Success"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client2/Failures"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client3/Date"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client3/TotalTests"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client3/Success"/>
        </td>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client3/Failures"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background:Gray">
        <td style="height:20"> - </td>
        <td></td>               
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, you've tagged the question "xslt-2.0" but shown a 1.0 stylesheet - which version do you actually need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
<xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
```

as the first child of the `for-each` to reverse the processing order. If you do this you will also need to change your "last five" test because you now want to process the *first* five nodes in the reverse-order list. Alternatively it might make more sense to move the "last five" logic into a predicate on the `for-each` select expression instead of using an `if`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="(Automation/Run)[position() > last()-5]">
  <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
```

This approach will work in XSLT 1.0 as well as 2.0 (you've tagged the question 2.0 but your current stylesheet is `version="1.0"` so it's not clear which you actually need).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this. This method is designed to avoid iterating through what might be a large number of instances in order to find the last 5. In your case that might not be a factor and there might be a much better method.

The xml I used:

```
<root>
    <e>a</e>
    <e>b</e>
    <e>c</e>
    <e>d</e>
    <e>e</e>
    <e>f</e>
    <e>g</e>
    <e>h</e>
    <e>i</e>
    <e>j</e>
</root>
```

the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:TESA="tesa.philips.com">

    <xsl:variable name="last" select="count(/root/e)"/> <!-- similar to what you did -->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="recurse"> <!-- begin recursion with last e node -->
            <xsl:with-param name="which" select="$last"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="recurse"> <!-- each time through process a single e -->
        <xsl:param name="which"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/e[$which]"/> <!-- get just the one we want -->
        <xsl:if test="$which &gt; ($last - 4)"> <!-- check to see if we have some left to do -->
            <xsl:call-template name="recurse">
                <xsl:with-param name="which" select="$which - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e"> <!-- and here process it however you want. -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalized approach to do output the top N of an arbitrary list of items, with the added benefit of being freely sortable.

For the example I sort on `position()`, of course, but you can change the sort expression to whatever you need.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="Automation">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Run" mode="top-n">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" />
        <xsl:with-param name="n" select="5"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="top-n">
    <xsl:param name="n" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $n">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Run">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <!-- or whatever you want to do with a <Run> -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just switch sort order to ascending in order to get the first N items, respectively.

Note the template mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
<xsl:for-each select="subsequence(reverse(Automation/Run), 1, 5)">
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

although it might be a fraction faster to extract the last 5 using subsequence, and then reverse these five only.